# Vertically centered multiline textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically centre multiple lines of text in a `textarea` element.

I have used the attribute `contenteditable="true"` on a `div` and then embedded my `textarea` elements in those divs. By setting the css properties of the divs to:

```
div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

This works for a single line textarea. But I aim to have multiple lines of text, which right now will disappear beyond the borders of the div when I press return to type the next line. I have tried setting `overflow: visible !important` for the div and the textarea, but this only expands the textarea to about 4 lines and no more than that. Another problem with that solution is that if my textarea is only a couple lines, they are not vertically centered anymore.

How can I vertically center multiple lines of text in a textarea, **and make them visible**? I'm looking for the simplest possible solution.

```js
$('td div').prop("readonly", true);
$('td div').attr("contenteditable", false);
```

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

td {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
}

td div {
/*overflow: visible; !important*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  outline: none;
  border-color: red;
}

textarea {
/* overflow: visible; !important */
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   outline: none;
   cursor: default;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
   resize: none;
   border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
          <thead>
            <tr class="days-of-the-week">
              <th scope="col" class="time-col"></th>
              <th scope="col">Sunday</th>
              <th scope="col">Monday</th>
              <th scope="col">Tuesday</th>
              <th scope="col">Wednesday</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" class="rowHdr">10:00am</th>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>           
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" class="rowHdr">10:30am</th>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>           
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" class="rowHdr">11:00am</th>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>           
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" class="rowHdr">11:30am</th>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" class="rowHdr">12:00pm</th>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>
              <td rowspan=""><div contenteditable="true"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></div></td>          
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

I have shown all element borders just to help illustrate the problem. 
The divs border is red. The textarea's border is green (Side note: I'm also not sure why they are different widths).

Comment: For me, the text is perfectly centered and a scroll bar appears when the text spans too many lines. I'm not sure I understand the issue. Also, out of curiosity, isn't a `textarea` inside an editable `div` more than you need? Wouldn't one or the other do the trick? Not sure on that one, the `contenteditable` attribute was actually new to me.

Comment: @domdom That is a good point. I tried getting rid of the textarea and just typing in the div. It works as expected, except that, as I type it will expand the width of its container, which I don't like. I will try to specify an exact width and see if that helps. Good comment.

Comment: All I had to do was get rid of the textarea (which is redundant). Then set a max-width for my `td`. Along with everything else, this solves the problem!
Thanks for the tip

Comment: Awesome, glad I could be of help!